# How to auto refresh a specific div using jQuery else in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I hope you are having a lovely weekend.

I added some simple code, which displays the time remaining until a specified date and time, into a php file.

For example:

```
<div class="time-remained">
// php code for displaying time remaining
</div>
```

I want the time to be auto refreshed every second. To do this, is it possible to auto-refresh the specific div per second using jQuery or other methods?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I would not use PHP for any of this. I would only use JS/JQuery. What have you tried so far? Please add your code.

Comment: @Twisty. The php code calculates the time difference between the end date (specified within a WordPress plugin) and the current date. To calculate the time difference, I used the code found at http://findnerd.com/list/view/Date-difference-between-two-timezones-in-PHP/862/.

Comment: use setInterval() http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have an ideal,

write a JavaScript function to make a request to your php time script and use setInterval() to refresh your div every seconds.

**Example only.**

```
<script>
  function chk_ajax_with_php(){
    var params = date.now();

       var url = "URL_TO_PHP_SCRIPT";
            $.ajax({
                           type: 'POST',
                           url: url,
                           dataType: 'html',
                           data: params,
                           beforeSend: function() {
                          document.getElementById("time-remained").innerHTML= "CHECKING TIME";
                                     },
                           complete: function() {

                           },
                           success: function(html) {


                                 /// html represent your outcome
                                 if(html=='keep'){

                                    chk_ajax_with_php();

                                 }else{

                                      document.getElementById("time-remained").innerHTML= html;
                                 }

                           }
                   });
}

setTimeout(function(){chk_ajax_with_php()}, 1000);


</script>

<div class="time-remained">
// THIS DIV WILL REFRESH EVERY PER SECOND
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CoffeeScript and Moment.js to dynamically increase the clock. Have a look at this link. [Coffeescript: Dynamically update time with moment js with coffeescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13924789/coffeescript-dynamically-update-time-with-moment-js-with-coffeescript)

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try to use the code you suggested.